# Air for Android - Initialization

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, air-android

I have created an app through *Air 2.5* and it works perfectly on my computer but on Android it's like the initialization fails.

Those functions are not getting fired:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler); 
resizeHandler() 
setupJSONText()
```

The code is located in the first layer from the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, AIR 2.5 is very much out of date.  Is there a reason you're using 2.5?  3.2 is the latest (perhaps currently in 'release candidate').  There were some significant performance enhancements in 2.7 and later.  I'd be very hesitant to use a version as old as 2.5.  Find the latest production version (3.1 currently) [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.edu.html), while the 3.2 preview release is [here](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/air3-2/).

Here are instructions for [overlaying the AIR SDK update onto Flash CS5 installation](http://blog.prevail.co.nz/2011/06/21/overlaying-air2-7-in-flash-cs5/), and also more official (from Adobe) instructions for [overlaying AIR updates onto CS5.5](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/908/cpsid_90810.html).

As for your code - are you intending to call resizeHandler initially and at every stage resize event?  How do you know those functions aren't being called - is there some visible output expected on the screen?  Can you post more code so we can see what you're expecting?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'm using _Air 2.5_ because it was the latest version I could get for _Adobe Flash CS 5_ when I started with the app back then. Do I need to wait for _Flash CS 6_ to be released to get my app published as _Air 3_? (Because my code and graphics are in a .fla file)

Comment: Added links to overlaying instructions for updating the AIR version in your Flash CS5 installation.